# need advice on mysql data base design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I need to build application where users can search/filter products by multiple characteristics. There are 25 product groups. Each product group have around 10 product characteristics.  I have a few data base design solutions, but none of them seems appropriate enough:

1. Create 25 tables per each group with column names storing product group characteristics.
2. Create one table with all products and as many columns as there are product characteristics (~ 200)
3. EAV: create 1 table for all characteristics and 1 table with all products and their attributes stored in rows, not in column names. This solution will result in writing a lot of application code, because I won't be able to select a product with all characteristics in one row. I will have to write application code to group mysql results.

I believe there are already solutions for problems like mine. Thanks for help.

EDIT:

In most cases the characteristics in groups are entirely different. These are starter/alternator components. Only around 25% of characteristics can overlap, like physical characteristics, length, diameter, etc.

Comment: (a) Are you saying each group has different characteristics? Entirely different? (b) Can you edit your Question to provide some examples, not your real problem, but a simplified fictional example we can relate to? As written, the Question is not clear.

Comment: What volumetry are we talking about here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:
Create 3 tables; Groups, GroupCharacteristics,Products.

1. Groups is linked to both tables.
2. GroupCharacteristics will have the list of characteristics, using 3 columns, (1)GroupName,(2)CharacteristicName,(3)Mapping [Values for mapping could be C01,C02 through C10]
   You will use mapping later on. 
   One group has many characteristics so it's a one to many link.
3. Products will have 12 Columns; (1)ProductName/Id,(2)GroupName,(3)C01,(4)C02 ... (12)C10.
   The C** columns will be filled with the values of the related characteristics in order to keep them mapped correctly.

**Groups:**
[GroupName]
1-Vehicles
2-Furniture
**Characteristics:**
[Map][Group][Characteristic]
1-C01 | Vehicles  | Length
2-C02 | Vehicles  | Volume
3-C03 | Vehicles  | Type
4-C01 | Furniture | Height
5-C02 | Furniture | Volume
6-C03 | Furniture | Length
**Products:**
[ProdName][Group][C01][C02][C03]...
1-Car | Vehicles | 2  | 50 | Hatchback
2-Jet | Vehicles | 10 | 70 | Null
3-Table| Furniture | 1 | null | 1.6
4-Cup | Furniture |0.1 | 0.12 | null

String col = Select Map from Characteristics where Group = 'Vehicles' and Characteristic = ' Type'
-- this returns the column (in this case C03) then --
String sql = "Select ProdName from Products where Group = 'Vehicles' and "+col+"='Hatchback'"
-- this will build the query in a string then you just execute it --
execute(sql)
-- in whatever language you're using this is just the basic idea behind the code you have to write.

Comment: This seems to be my 2nd solution. In Products table I will have to create around 200 columns.

Comment: You said you had at most 10 Characteristics for every product type (group).
The columns in the products table are reusable for different characteristics since you have the mapping field.

Comment: Yes, and each type has almost unique characteristics. There will be 25 types. Total amount of unique characteristics is around 200 (25*10).

Comment: You still only need 10 columns in Products.
200 rows in Characteristics.

Comment: Each product type has unique characteristics. If in Products I want to store all products as rows and all characteristics values in one row, I will have to store characteristic name as column name. If have have 200 unique characteristics, I will have to keep 200 columns. Those characteristics which do not apply to specif product type will have `NULL` values in rows. This is my second solution. I do not understand, how mapping will help me here.

Comment: I will show you an example when I can, if you still don't have an answer until then.

Comment: Yes, please. I do appreciate this.

Comment: Updated the answer with a small example

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what you mean. But how do I query products against characteristics? E.g. I need to find all vehicles with type Hatchback?

Comment: col = Select Map from Characteristics where Group = 'Vehicles' and Characteristic = ' Type' -- this returns the column (in this case C03) then -- sql = "Select ProdName from Products where Group = 'Vehicles' and "+col+"='Hatchback'" -- this will build the query in a string then you just execute it -- execute(sql) -- in whatever language you're using